# Array values are modified while sending them using message queue

Tags: c, linux, message-queue

I am sending a struct that has an array property. When I check the arrays on child process every array value seems correct, but when I send them using message queue and receive them, I see that in parent array values are different values such as `-38829` and so on. What could be the problem? I am inserting the code below.

```
            for (int i = 0; i < x; i++) {
                printf("count[i] = %d\n", aptr->count[i]); // these values are true, so I have to send them
            }
            mq_send(mq, (char *)&aptr, sizeof(struct a), 0);
            exit(0);
        }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < fileNo; i++)
        wait(NULL);

    mq_getattr(mq_t, &mq_attr_t);
    // allocation
    buflen2 = mq_attr_t.mq_msgsize;
    bufptr2 = (char *)malloc(buflen2);
   
    // receiving the mq
    while (fileNo) {
        mq_receive(mq_t, (char *)bufptr2, buflen2, NULL); // receive is not failed, I checked

        ptr = (struct a *)bufptr2;
        for (int i = 0; i < intervalCount; i++) {
            temp[i] = ptr->count[i]; // temparr was empty beforehand, init here
            printf("temp[i] %d\n", temp[i]); //the values are different and wrong here
        }
```

What could be the problem? I tested a lot of stuff and I am sure something is broken while sending my struct message.

Comment: Are you sure that `temp` is in the correct type and the `count` member is an integer, as you print it as such with `"%d"`?

Comment: just checked it again and yes :|

Comment: The `struct a` does not seem to be defined anywhere. Also, `mq_...` functions seem to be missing error handling.

Comment: Check out what a [mcve] is and edit your question.

Comment: struct a is defined, this is a small code sample of a whole code sadly. I will try to edit and write a minimal reproducible example